# Action popup keystroke?

Tags: interface

Whenever an action of any kind is performed on an object in the layout window a control box or menu appears in the lower left corner, either closed as a small box with the name of the action taken and an opening button, or open with all the action options and data for tweaking.  Is there a keystroke to open or close that? I don't always want it open, like if I just move or resize something and suddenly there is this box blocking part of the view, but I'd like to be able to open it with a keystroke rather than a mouse click.

Comment: Hi :). Sure, simply collapse it and open it anytime through *Edit > Adjust Last Operation* [Shortcut: F9]

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks!